# Specific Pivot Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have been looking at pivoting columns and would be grateful of any help. I see plenty of examples for summing a row on the pivot but I have a different scenario. I have a field that is JSON which is parsed and the output gets placed in a view as so.

```
ID Name     StringValue
1  type     user
1  name     aeolos smith
1  access   admin
2  type     user
2  name     ramuh smith
2  access   author
```

I would like to Pivot this somehow to end up like the following.

```
type      name              access
user      aeolos smith      admin
user      ramuh smith       author
```

and so on for any entries with the identifier being the ID.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify what database you are using, but it your database supports windowing functions like `row_number()` then you can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression along with the row number to get the final result:

```
select 
  max(case when name = 'type' then stringvalue end) type,
  max(case when name = 'name' then stringvalue end) name,
  max(case when name = 'access' then stringvalue end) access
from
(
  select id, name, stringvalue,
    row_number() over(partition by name order by id) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by seq;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23972/2)

If your database supports the PIVOT function, then you will still use the `row_number()` windowing function along with pivot to get the final result:

```
select type, name, access
from
(
  select name nm, stringvalue,
    row_number() over(partition by name order by id) seq
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(stringvalue)
  for nm in (type, name, access)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23972/4)

Comment: Thanks you that was exactly what I was looking for. It was SQL Server 2012, apologises for not stating that in my post.